# Remove line breaks from an excel cells using python

Tags: python

I am trying to converting excel file to csv file. the data in the excel file is like below:

[image]

My code to convert to csv:

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
for excel_file in glob.glob('C:/Talend/DEV/MARKET_OPTIMISATION/IMS/*Extract*.xls'):
    print(excel_file)
    data_xls = pd.read_excel(excel_file, 'Untitled', index=0,skiprows=1, sep='|',encoding='utf-8')
    #data_xlx.pop
    data_xls1=data_xls.replace('\r\n','')
    data_xls1.to_csv('C:/Talend/DEV/MARKET_OPTIMISATION/IMS/IMS_Raw_data.csv',sep='|',encoding='utf-8')
```

The output of the above code is:

[image]

but I need out put like this
[image]

can anyone please help me in removing the line breaks on the excel file.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your dataframe, the newlines are in the column names. And the column names are not affected when you use the replace method of the dataframe, only the data are.

So in your example, you should explicitely change the column names:

```
data_xls = pd.read_excel(excel_file, 'Untitled', index=0,skiprows=1, sep='|',encoding='utf-8')
data_xls.columns = data_xls.columns.map(lambda x: x.replace('\r','').replace('\n', ''))
```

Comment: @Ballesta, I am facing one more problem here. I have data like 'NA' while converting to  the xls file to csv, it is considering NA as null value. can you please suggest how read the data as is.

Answer (score 0):

try replace \r and \n separately

```
mystring = mystring.replace('\n', ' ').replace('\r', '')
```

if it fails just .split() string and then .join() list elements

Comment: tried using replace separately also but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
import re
re.sub("\n|\r", "", mystring)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use regex=True in your command, like below:

```
import re
data_xls = data_xls.replace('\n', ' ', regex=True)
```

or better would be to replace any kind of whitespace with a single space:

```
data_xls = data_xls.replace('\s', ' ', regex=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace `\t` (Tabs).
This will get you all records inline.

```
mystring = mystring.replace('\t','')
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace `\t` (Tabs).
This will get you all records inline.

```
mystring = mystring.replace('\t','')
```

You can paste part of your data [here](https://www.soscisurvey.de/tools/view-chars.php) to see what chars are hidden in your data.